# I'm trying to remove items from a jList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am very new to Java, having used Visual Basic for some years. I have created a basic GUI using NetBeans. It contains a jList, called lstMain. I have created a DefaultListModel called LISTMODEL, and I can add String items to the jList. When I try to remove items using

```
int M = lstMain.getSelectedIndex();
LISTMODEL.remove(M);
```

odd things happen. Sometimes the list item is removed, leaving one item fewer. This is what I'd expect. Sometimes the list items appear to remain in place, unchanged, but the last item is inaccessible. If I click on an accessible item it changes to what I’d have expected - ie what was the next item. Sometimes the items do change, but the last one is still inaccessible. This all seems a far cry from the ease of use of a Visual Basic listbox. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: have you tried just invalidating the list?

Comment: Since you're new to Java, please read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367 . It is VERY recommended.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @twall no need to manually invalidate anything - the model will notify its listeners, all internal updates will happen automagically :-)

Comment: while you are at reading and learning - please learn java naming conventions and stick to them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me - try this SSCCE:

```
public class SimpleList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("List example");
        final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("Hello");
        model.addElement("World");

        final JList list = new JList(model);
        frame.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");
        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int sel = list.getSelectedIndex();
                if (sel >= 0)
                {
                    model.removeElementAt(sel);
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(remove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your changes to the listModel are happening in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

In concrete terms, use this:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int M = lstMain.getSelectedIndex();
            LISTMODEL.remove(M);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes - although if you are triggering the remove() from a JButton, for example, then you will already be in the EDT, so the invokeLater() won't be needed.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (konnte ich mir jetzt nicht verkneifen aka SCNR :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Steve was quoting the OP's code, so that's a bit harsh!

Comment: @DNA I'm aware of that, no harshness meant as you can see at the end of my comment :-) On the other hand, I think that experienced developers shouldn't simply quote bad style from newbie questions, but correct the most obvious mistakes and drop a hint as to why they changed it

Comment: @kleopatra OK sorry, missed the "SCNR" entirely!

Comment: This is indeed harsh... I _do_ know the Java naming conventions but decided not to post code that wouldn't compile for the OP.